# ReactJS: How to get state value into container?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I need to get data from DB depending on a search string value. Therefore I'm using an input field. The search string is stored as a state value.

The data for the component comes from a container (using npm meteor/react-meteor-data).

Now my problem is, how do I get the search string into the container to set the parameter for the publication?

**container/example.js**

```
export default createContainer((prop) => {
    Meteor.subscribe('images', searchString) // How to get searchString?
    return { files: Images.find({}).fetch() }
}, Example)
```

**component/example.jsx**

```
class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            searchString: ''
        }
    }

    searchImage(event) {
        const searchString = event.target.value
        this.setState({ searchString })
    }

    render() {
        return (<Input onChange={ this.searchImage.bind(this) }/>)
    }
}

export default Example
```

**publication**

```
Meteor.publish('images', function(search) {
    return Images.find({ title: search }).cursor
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can create two different components: a parent and a child, and you can wrap child component with createContainer HOC like the following

**childComponent.js**

```
const Example = (props) => {
    return <Input onChange={props.searchImage}/>
}

export default createContainer(({searchString}) => {
Meteor.subscribe('images', searchString)
    return { files: Images.find({}).fetch() }
}, Example)
```

**parentComponent.js**

```
class ExampleWrapper extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            searchString: ''
        }
    }

    searchImage = (event)  => {
        const searchString = event.target.value
        this.setState({ searchString })
    } // instead of binding this, you can also use arrow function that 
      // takes care of binding

    render() {
        return (<Example searchImage={this.searchImage} searchString={this.state.searchString} {...this.props} />)
    }
}

export default ExampleWrapper
```

The idea is, since `createContainer` is a higher order component, it doesn't have access to the props of any component wrapped by it.

What we need to do is, passing the value of `searchString` from a parent component. 
The way to do is the following:
`ExampleWrapper` has a state called `searchString` and `Example` component  has a prop called `searchString`. We can set the value of `searchString` prop to `state.searchString`.
Since the `default export` corresponds to `createContainer({..some logic…}, Example})`, `createContainer` can make use of prop called `searchString`.

In order to change the value of `state.searchString` we also passed `searchImage` function as a prop to `Example` component. Whenever there is a change event, `onChange` triggers `searchImage` function that updates the value of `state.searchString`. And eventually, the minute the value of `state.searchString` changes `searchString` prop’s value changes thus your subscription result also changes

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange={ (e)=> {this.setState({ searchString: $(e.target).val() }) } }
```

This is how we assign values to our internal state properties :)

EDIT: I appear to have misunderstood the question...